# Trigger VBA code when changing to a different mail in reading pane

Tags: vba, email, outlook

Once I read new mails from a specific sender I would like to move them from the Inbox to a subfolder.

I set Outlook to mark mails as read as soon as I open them. To make sure I can read through the mail I want to move the mail only when I close it/change to a different mail. (*Note that I'm using the reading pane.*)

I tried the `Explorer.SelectionChange` event but it triggers multiple times when I change to a new mail.

```
Private WithEvents expl As Outlook.Explorer

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set expl = Application.ActiveExplorer()
End Sub

Private Sub expl_SelectionChange()
    MsgBox "Selection changed"
End Sub
```

Why does this trigger multiple times?

How do I get a reference to the mail item I'm "closing"?

Answer (score 0):

> Why does this trigger multiple times?

I guess (*I could be wrong*), it is because of the `View` that you have. The above said behaviour was not noticed for `RPO` or `Preview` mode. When you have, say, a `Compact` view the selection change happens two times? First when the item is selected and the 2nd time when the item contents are displayed. But like I said, I could be wrong...

> Alternative

It would have been easier if Outlook had `Application.EnableEvents = False` like MS Excel. Hope this alternative helps?

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents expl As Outlook.Explorer
Dim DisableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set expl = Application.ActiveExplorer()
End Sub

Private Sub expl_SelectionChange()
    If DisableEvents = True Then
        DisableEvents = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    MsgBox "Selection changed"
    
    DisableEvents = True
End Sub
```